# How do I get/inject the current SSLSession in Jersey server?

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS application (Jersey 2.22) in which I need to get the peer SSL client certificates (the server is enabled for mutual SSL authentication).

What I'm trying to achieve is something in the lines of:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String clientCertificates() {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    SSLSessionContext clientContext = sslContext.getClientSessionContext();
    byte[] sessionId = clientContext.getIds().nextElement();
    SSLSession clientSession = clientContext.getSession(sessionId);
    Certificate[] certificates = clientSession.getPeerCertificates();
    return "The client provided " + certificates.length + " certificates.";
}
```

but this throws a NoSuchElementException at clientContext.getIds().nextElement() even if the client DID provide a valid SSL certificate that the server accepted to establish the session (I'm trying this with Glassfish 4, WildFly 9 and WildFly 10).

Note: The web.xml CLIENT-CERT auth-method is NOT what I need: I need to get hands a reference to the client certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this (unchecked) method to get the provided certificates in a `ContainerRequestFilter` from a `ContainerRequestContext`, if any:

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) requestContext.getProperty("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        Principal principal = certificates[0].getSubjectX500Principal();
    }

}
```